# Another "Dimension too large" question: PSTricks plot

Tags: errors, pstricks

I'm currently using Pstricks to plot a datafile into a basic x-y figure.
My actual code is:

```
\psset{xunit=.07cm,yunit=0.00025cm} 
\begin{pspicture}(1915,10000)(2015,30500)
\psaxes[Dx=10,Dy=15000,Ox=1915,Oy=13000,ticksize=-3pt,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(1915,13000)(2015,28000)[,-90][X (s.),0]
\fileplot[plotstyle=dots, dotscale=0.8]{Figures/figure20-B1.prn}
\end{pspicture}
```

Part of my data is:

```
1922,27169
1923,23561
1925,21835
1926,20167
1928,20003
1942,19910
1944,19123
1952,18585
1953,18115
1961,17110
1965,16503
1975,15629
1976,14947
1979,14758
1983,14288
1986,13735
1998,13137
```

It works just fine, except I do not have any label in the Y axis (because of the `Dy=15000`). The main thing is that I could actually have ticks on the y axis by reducing `Dy` (say `Dy=2000`) and increasing `yunit` in `psset`. However, I tried in and it do not work at all.

I tried `\pstScalePoints`, local y-axis scaling (`yunit=xxx` in the `fileplot` parameters, although I'm not sure `yunit` is part of the authorized variables of `fileplot` parameter) and it didn't change the thing.

I would greatly appreciate some help on this redundant topic (I already browsed associated `Dimension too large` topics and tried some alternative but gosh, I must be wrong somewhere...).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4):

I created a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your code snippet and it works fine:

```
\begin{filecontents}{figure20-B1.prn}
1922,27169
1923,23561
1925,21835
1926,20167
1928,20003
1942,19910
1944,19123
1952,18585
1953,18115
1961,17110
1965,16503
1975,15629
1976,14947
1979,14758
1983,14288
1986,13735
1998,13137
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=.07cm,yunit=0.00025cm} 
\begin{pspicture}(1915,10000)(2015,30500)
\psaxes[Dx=10,Dy=15000,Ox=1915,Oy=13000,ticksize=-3pt,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(1915,13000)(2015,28000)[,-90][X (s.),0]
\fileplot[plotstyle=dots, dotscale=0.8]{figure20-B1.prn}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]